# Чем отличается CriteriaQuery и CriteriaBuilder в JPA Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
interface Specification<T> {
    Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb);
}
```

В данном пример для чего `CriteriaQuery`?
Нигде не видел, чтобы использовали.
`CriteriaBuilder` нужен для формирования  предиката для запроса, правильно? А `CriteriaQuery` для чего, сделать запрос и протестировать работу предиката?

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере `CriteriaQuery` вам нужен для составления дополнительных условий запроса, если вам таковые нужны будут. К ним могут относится условия сортировки, группировки.

К примеру, при написании спецификации вам нужно будет выполнить сортировку по конкретному столбцу. Вы так и укажите:

```
query.orderBy(new OrderImpl(...));
```

Comment: А как потом query  использовать в cb?

Comment: @Venot в данном случае никак. Все команды, которые вы примените к query, автоматически будут учтены при построении запроса.